# Inapp billing which product type to choose for premium upgrade of app for one year

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I have a app in which if users selects upgrade your app from menu then i have to do inapp billing to upgrade app and then everything inside app becomes free for one year. And after one year it should come back to normal way.

I have created merchant account and done all setup for implementing Google inapp biling.

Now i wanted to add inapp products but i am not sure which one to select, Managed products or unmanaged products or subscription.

- Managed products is aimed at one time downloads then you 'own that object'.
- UnManaged products is for multiple downloads of the same thing to 'top something up'.
- All subscriptions are auto-renewing, for every app and game and every type of subscription product. After the transaction, Google Play manages recurring billing and keeps users informed of new charges, sending them an email with each renewal. At any time, users can visit My Apps in the Play Store app to view their subscriptions and cancel any subscription as needed.

So in this subscriptions product it does this renewing thing but i wanted is make app free for one year only and after 1 year if user wants to upgrade then he again upgrades through the app.

Which product type should i choose for upgrading app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use managed products. This product will be synced between all devices and preserved by Google Play Services until you consume it. The main point is not to consume the item so it will be available forever once purchased.

Of course you can utilize unmanaged products the same way but it's rather deprecated thing in in-app billing.

Comment: Will i be able to buy that same managed product again once he consumes that product after one year.

Comment: @Nav Yes, once the item is consumed it can be purchased again.